# attempt at "onlyWhitelist" modifier in solidity

Tags: solidity

I'm attempting to create an ERC20 token that is only transferrable to a list of whitelisted addresses. Here's what I've come up with.. for some reason the transaction fails when I try to launch the contract on mist.. saying it will fail after spending all gas. Does anyone see any glaring issues? Thank you!

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;

contract WHITELIST {

    mapping(address => bool) public DignityWhitelist;

    modifier isWhitelisted() {
        require(DignityWhitelist[msg.sender] == true);
        _; 
    }

    function WHITELIST (address initialAccount) public {
        if(initialAccount == 0x0) {
            initialAccount = msg.sender;
        }
        DignityWhitelist[initialAccount];
    }

    function enableWhitelist(address whitelistAddress) external {
        DignityWhitelist[whitelistAddress] = true;
    }

    function disableWhitelist(address removeAddress) external {
        DignityWhitelist[removeAddress] = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The contract won't fail, but it's not secure. You're allowing anyone to enable/disable whitelist entries. You need to restrict access to the contract owner.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;

contract WHITELIST {
    address owner;

    mapping(address => bool) public DignityWhitelist;

    modifier isWhitelisted() {
        require(DignityWhitelist[msg.sender] == true);
        _; 
    }

    modifier isOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    function WHITELIST() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
        DignityWhitelist[msg.sender] = true;
    }

    function enableWhitelist(address whitelistAddress) external isOwner {
        DignityWhitelist[whitelistAddress] = true;
    }

    function disableWhitelist(address removeAddress) external isOwner {
        require(removeAddress != owner);
        DignityWhitelist[removeAddress] = false;
    }
}
```

You'll need to add the `isWhitelisted` modifier to functions you want to restrict access to.

Comment: Thank you Adam! Very much appreciated.